# Formatting a Mifare Ultralight to NDEF throw IO Exception

Tags: android, format, nfc, mifare, ndef

I want to format a never-used MIFARE Ultralight card using the code below:

```
NdefFormatable formatable = NdefFormatable.get(tag);
if (formatable != null) {
    String result = "Afifly";
    try {
        formatable.connect();

        try {
            formatable.format(new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_EMPTY, null, null, null)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // let the user know the tag refused to format
            System.out.println("error ");//+getStackTrace(e));
            result = "Fail 1";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // let the user know the tag refused to connect
        System.out.println("eeeerrror 2"+e);
        result = "Fail 2";
    } finally {
        try {
            formatable.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

But it always throws an IOException (without any meaningful message) when calling the method `formatable.format(...)`.

I tried with several other cards, all with the same result. However, these cards can be formatted using NXP TagWriter for example.

I already found the question/answer "[Formatting a Mifare Ultralight C to NDEF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29745097/formatting-a-mifare-ultralight-c-to-ndef/30375448#30375448)", but this solution does not work for me. I still get the same IOException.

The first four pages (pages 0-3) of the tag contain the following bytes:

```
04 F1 E9 94
42 AB 4A 80
23 48 00 00  (all lock-bits cleared)
00 00 00 00  (no capability container)
```

Thus, the tag is empty and not locked.

Comment: What technologies are enumerated with `tag.getTechList()`? Does the IOException contain any message (`e.getMessage()`)? What's the contents of pages 3-5 of the tag before you try to use `format(...)`?

Comment: There are 3 techs enumerated :
`android.nfc.tech.NfcA`
`android.nfc.tech.MifareUltraLight`
`android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable` and `e.getMessage()` print out `null`

Comment: When i read on it, it gave me a byte array containing values `4 -15 -23 -108 66 -85 74 -128 35 72 and 6 zero` so if it is 4 bytes pages, it gave me `35 72 0 0` on page 3 and only 0 on 4 and 5 ... every card not formatted has something different writing on it when I call `MifareUltralight.get(tag).readPages(0)`

Comment: The tag is indeed empty and not locked so formatting should norammly work if your Android device supports formatting of that tag type. One more thing you could try is to use a different NDEF message (e.g. some message that contains a non-empty record). If that does not work either your device platform might not support formatting of that tag type using `NdefFormatable ` even though it incorrectly provides the `NdefFormatable` tag technology. Unfortunately, such devices do exist. If that's the case I would suggest that you manually perform the formatting procedure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried with a non empty record without success ... If my device platform do not support formatting, why formatting is working on the same device with an app as tagwriter ? They are using something else that NdefFormatable ? What so ?

Comment: Right, NXP TagWriter, for instance, uses its own formatting logic on top of low-level tag commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely reason for getting an `IOException` when calling `NdefFormatable.format()` on an empty MIFARE Ultralight tag is that your device does not support "formatting" (i.e. initializing as NFC Forum Type 2 tag) that type of tag. If that's the case, it is clearly a bug that you even see the `NdefFormatable` technology.

The only option that you have in that case, is that you manually perform the formatting procedure (see the NFC Forum Type 2 Tag Operation specification for details). That is also what various tag writing apps (e.g. NXP TagWriter) do. For a MIFARE Ultralight (MF0ICU1) tag (**don't try to use this for larger tags!**), something like this would work:

```
NfcA nfcA = NfcA.get(tag);
if (nfcA != null) {
    try {
        nfcA.connect();
        nfcA.transceive(new byte[] {
            (byte)0xA2,  // WRITE
            (byte)0x03,  // page = 3
            (byte)0xE1, (byte)0x10, (byte)0x06, (byte)0x00  // capability container (mapping version 1.0, 48 bytes for data available, read/write allowed)
        });
        nfcA.transceive(new byte[] {
            (byte)0xA2,  // WRITE
            (byte)0x04,  // page = 4
            (byte)0x03, (byte)0x00, (byte)0xFE, (byte)0x00  // empty NDEF TLV, Terminator TLV
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        try {
            nfcA.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Phoenix Thanks for spotting and correcting the copy-paste mistake (wrong page number). Not sure why your edit was rejected though...

Comment: Do you have any idea how to refresh the tag techlist after formatting a card, without a second touch ? The format succeed, but I can't write on the card immediatly because the tag as the same techlist as before formatting, and to refresh it, I need to take the card of and the put it on to detect it with the good techlist ...

Comment: @Phoenix No, that's simply not possible (there is some evil and unstable tricks like disabling and re-enabling NFC discovery, but don't even try to do that...) If you need to immediately write an NDEF message, you also need to write that using low-level commands. You can do that by filling the NDEF message into the (currently empty) NDEF TLV.

Comment: Thanks, but I finally decided to write my own hexa bits using `nfcA.transceive()` to not get embarrassed with ndefMessage ... Thanks for your app that helped me a lot to see what I was writing on it !

Comment: Sorry for "stupid" comment, but can it be used to "emulate" Mifare Ultralight card? So, for example, senging data to a reader with .connect() ?

Comment: @MarcoSanfilippo All the above is about NFC reader functionality of Android devices. There is no way to use this *reader functionality* to interact with another *reader*.